# System lags while using application or playing games

Tags: crash

From the first time, I am facing some problems. The problem is, All time, when I try to play any games or use any application, It crashes. When I try to open any application, It takes 3 or 4 minutes to open. And, the system animations are not seen. I can't use the internet correctly for the lagging.  I think, It's because of running Windows 10 beside it. What do you think? Why is it hapenning

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.